# Scrolling with one div positioned absolute right

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position

So I want the inner right div to be scrollable along with the first inner div when the total viewport size along with which the outer div width decreases. If the screen size is too wide, then the inner right div should appear at the extreme right end without any scrolling.

Currently if we use position: absolute and right: 0 in the #inner-right-div, then the #inner-right-div overlays into the #inner-first-div which is not what we want. We want both the inner divs to be space separated and scrollable when the max-width reduces.

Edit. The #inner-right-div needs to always be right aligned with the #outer-div, irrespective of the max-width of the #outer-div (may be 5%, 20%, 50% or anything)

```css
#outer-div {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 5%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#inner-first-div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#inner-right-div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <div id="outer-div">
    <div id="inner-first-div">
      StackOverflow
    </div>
    <div id="inner-right-div">
      ABCD
    </div>
  </div>

</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you omit `position` and `right` the `#inner-right-div` is aligned right of the `#inner-first-div`.

**Working example**:

```css
#outer-div {
  max-width: 5%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#inner-first-div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#inner-right-div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <div id="outer-div">
    <div id="inner-first-div">
      StackOverflow
    </div>
    <div id="inner-right-div">
      ABCD
    </div>
  </div>

</head>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes but now the inner right div will not be right aligned with the rightmost end of the width of the screen, if the max-width of the outer-div is increased (let us say 20% now). I wanted the inner-right div to always be right aligned with the outer div, whatever the max-width of the outer-div may be.

Comment: Since i don't understand, maybe it would be a good idea to post one or more images of the look you want.